# Kafka Streams: Is it possible to use different timestamps for deletion than for stream processing?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka Streams 2.0.

My use case: being able to (partially) reprocess data with event-created time (user-defined from original data and set via TimestampExtractor) from the beginning of history for a reprocessing application, running alongside a long-running non-stop application, sending data to output topics (both applications will read and send to the same output topics, which are used to build state).

Stores are built from these topics, and include windowing by session. Imagine I'd like to give a one-month retention (for out-of-order events and consumption) to those topics - when reprocessing, if using event-time, I'll be processing (and generating) older-than-a-month events.

Using `message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime` as per [KIP-32](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message) to avoid deletion, will generate wrong data in the state stores (since timestamps would be incorrect and they would be used for e.g. sessioning).

Using event-time, keeping full retention, and applying purging data after reprocessing is finished and consumed, is tedious but would help reducing size in topics - however, what about stores that are built from them? E.g. in order to hold the data while the reprocessing happens, I would have to set an `until` setting of pseudo-infinity, but DSL-created stores are (or should be) read-only, not manipulated.

So, back to the title:

- Is it possible (or envisioned) to use different timestamps for deletion than for stream processing?
- Any other way to better work around it?

Comment: Why do you need to set your own timestamp via `forward()` ?

Comment: My bad, I meant using LogAppendTime to avoid deletion. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For Streams, using `LogAppendTime` for repartition topics is a miss configuration. Also note, that you won't loose any data in repartition topics because those are created with retention time of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-284%3A+Set+default+retention+ms+for+Streams+repartition+topics+to+Long.MAX_VALUE). Streams uses `purgeData` API to delete data from repartition topics after they are consumed (cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6150) to avoid unbounded grows.

Thus, I would recommend to reconfigure all repartition topics via `log.message.timestamp.type` (ie, topic level config).

Comment: @matthias-j-sax I understand that LogAppendTime for reparititon topics would totally replace time semantics of original messages and make the repartitioning outcome non reproducible. Is that why you say it is a miss-configuration?

Comment: Yes, that is why it's considered a miss-configuration.